# Installing r7rs egg in Chicken Scheme fails

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I’m trying to get R7RS support in Chicken Scheme via installing the `r7rs` egg.
However, it fails while installing the `matchable` egg.

The following is the log produced by executing `sudo chicken-install r7rs -v`:

```
checking r7rs ...                                                                                                       
checking platform for `r7rs'                                                                                            
checking dependencies for `r7rs'                                                                                        
 missing: matchable, srfi-1, srfi-13                                                                                    
matchable located at /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable                                                             
srfi-1 located at /root/.cache/chicken-install/srfi-1                                                                   
srfi-13 located at /root/.cache/chicken-install/srfi-13                                                                 
checking srfi-13 ...          
checking platform for `srfi-13'                             
checking dependencies for `srfi-13'                         
 missing: srfi-14             
srfi-14 located at /root/.cache/chicken-install/srfi-14     
checking srfi-14 ...          
checking platform for `srfi-14'                             
checking dependencies for `srfi-14'                         
checking srfi-1 ...           
checking platform for `srfi-1'                              
checking dependencies for `srfi-1'                          checking matchable ...        checking platform for `matchable'                           
checking dependencies for `matchable'                       
install order:                
("matchable" "srfi-1" "srfi-14" "srfi-13" "r7rs")           
building matchable            running script /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable/matchable.build.sh
executing: "sh /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable/matchable.build.sh"
   /usr/bin/csc -regenerate-import-libraries -setup-mode -static -I /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable -emit-link-fi
le /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable/matchable.link -host -D compiling-extension -c -unit matchable -D compiling-st
atic-extension -C -I/root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable -O2 -d1 matchable.scm -o /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchab
le/matchable.static.o         
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 256: 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' '/root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable/matchable.static.c' -o '/root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable/matchable.static.o' -c  -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DHAVE_CHICKEN_CONFIG_H -DC_ENABLE_PTABLES -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/chicken-8b5V5S/chicken-5.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable -I/usr/include/chicken

Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code
256
"sh /root/.cache/chicken-install/matchable/matchable.build.sh"
```

I’m using Chicken 5.1.0 (rev 8e62f718), which is the latest version in the official repository for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Is there something I can do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to figure out why it got killed (which signal). Perhaps it ran out of memory?

You can try putting `CSC_OPTIONS=-verbose` in your environment to figure out which command failed, exactly. Then run it again by hand to find out more.

Comment: Yes, indeed it ran out of memory. I was running this on Google Cloud Platform using the free-tier compute engine. I chose the higher performance CPU/RAM, and it successfully compiled. Thanks!